# Weird characters while getting str from a file in C

Tags: c, file, debugging, printing, char

I tried to get the file's content and put it into a string. When I run my program and I print the string I get the file's content with some weird characters afterward.

My code:

```
int size = 0;
char ch = 0;
char* content = 0;
FILE* fs = fopen(file, "r");
//getting file's content and put it into a string
while (ch != EOF)
{
    ch = (char)fgetc(fs);
    size++;
    content = myRealloc(content, size);
    content[size - 1] = ch;
} 
printf("%s", content);
```

myRealloc:

```
char* myRealloc(char* array, int size)
{
    char* temp = 0;
    temp = realloc(array, size * sizeof(char));
    return temp;
}
```

The file's content:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

When I print:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h ²²²²ר─
```

Comment: What if `ch = (char)fgetc(fs);` is reading `EOF`? Also you didn't show how you print it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't understand you

Comment: what exactly didn't you understand? First of all, there is no `char` value that equals to `EOF`. It is `int`. So your `while` condition will never be true. Second, you test the value against `EOF` *after* you have assigned it into the array. Third - you didn't show the code responsible for the output.

Comment: Exactly - don't try to force the type to your understanding, use the type returned by the function - it is for a reason. There is a common assumption "I am using characters so my type must be `char`" but bear in mind that `'A'` is of type `int` which you can verify with `sizeof('A')`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Also, please don't [add chatty material](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) - editors tend to remove it. Brevity rules `:-)`

Comment: regarding: `temp = realloc(array, size * sizeof(char));` 1) the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: regarding: `content = myRealloc(content, size);` 1) always check !=NULL) the returned value to assure the original call to `realloc()` was successful.  2) when calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a 'temp' variable then check for !=NULL, and only if not NULL assign to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the pointer to the allocated memory will be overlayed with NULL,  The result is a memory leak.

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`.  so this statement: `char ch = 0;` should be: `int ch = 0;

Comment: regarding: `FILE* fs = fopen(file, "r");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (in fact when any C library function fails (except the `scanf()` family of function),call `perror()` with your error message and both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred will be (properly) output to `stderr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `ch = (char)fgetc(fs);` in the loop also try to print `EOF`, which you shouldn't.

Just Replace that block of code with

```
while ( (ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF) { /* fetch the char & check the condition */
      putchar(ch);
      size++;
      content = myRealloc(content, size);
      content[size - 1] = ch;
}
size++;
content = myRealloc(content, size);
content[size - 1] = '\0';
print("%s", content);
```

Also check the manual page of `fgetc()`  it returns `int`. So make `ch` type as `int`.

```
 int fgetc(FILE *stream);
```

Also `print("%s", content);` should be `printf("%s", content);` unless you didn't define `print()`.

Finally & most importantly once job is done, don't forgot to free the dynamically allocated memory by calling `free()` function.

Comment: Downvoting because `ch` needs to be type `int` if you are doing: `(ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF`.  See [this](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=stdio) from the C FAQ.

Comment: @achal Aren't you overflowing when doing: `content[size] = '\0';`?

Comment: Ok. Looks like you edited your post. But it's still wrong dude.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, you are writing on memory you did not allocate.

Comment: yes @JeremyPare valid point. OP needs to allocate for `'\0'` char and then terminates it.

Comment: So should i use myRealloc after got out of the while loop and then set the last char for "\0"? @achal

Comment: yes @ItayLavi you need to call once `myRealloc()` after coming out of loop.

Answer (score 4):

Add the null terminated character at the end:

```
int size = 0;
int ch = 0;
char* content = 0;
FILE* fs = fopen(file, "r");
//getting file's content and put it into a string
while ((ch = fgetc(fs)) != EOF)
{
    size++;
    content = myRealloc(content, size);
    content[size - 1] = (char)ch;
}
size++;
content = myRealloc(content, size);
content[size - 1] = '\0';
print("%s", content);
```

Edit: Also, as pointed out by @achal, you are trying to add the EOF character since when you read it you are already in the while loop. I modified my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not null terminated. You need to allocate enough space to hold the last null character, something like `temp = realloc(array, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));` and at the end do something like `content[size] = '\0'`. However, using `realloc` is probably the worst way to do what you're trying to do.

I'd use `stat` to find the file's size, then use `mmap` to map the file to memory and then `malloc` to the size of the file, and then `memcpy` to the `malloc`ed memory. `realloc` is evil, performance wise.

Here is an alternative that greatly outperforms the original code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    if (argc != 2){
      printf("Usage: %s {filename}\n",argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    // @todo: check if fd is valid
    struct stat st;
    int ret = fstat(fd,&st);
    // @todo: check ret
    void* mapped_memory = mmap(NULL,st.st_size,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
    // @todo: check mapped_memory that is not null
    char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(st.st_size + 1));
    // @todo: check that str is not null
    memcpy(str,mapped_memory,st.st_size);
    str[st.st_size] = '\0';
    printf("%s",str);
    free(str);
    munmap(mapped_memory,st.st_size);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (Pro-tip: when writing answers, HTML line breaks are very rarely required. Paragraphs are more readable, to group sentences on the same theme. Just use two Enter/Return presses to create a new para).

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
printf("%s", content);
```

the code that filled in the contents of `content` failed to NUL terminate that array of characters.

(and the allocated memory doesn't have enough room to append a NUL char)

so the call to `printf()` will keep outputting characters until it finds a NUL char.

That is the underlying reason for the junk characters being output.